# When I enter my username, "good job" isn't being displayed

Tags: python

```
import time

def Scenario2():

        film_comedy = ['Anchorman','The Hangover','Ted']
        film_horror = ['The Exorcist','The Shining','Scream']
        film_action = ['Die Hard','The Matrix','Batman']
        film_animation = ['Toy Story','The Incredibles','The Lion King']

        print("Hello, welcome to the online streaming service")
        username = len(input("Please Enter a username between 4 and 12 characters: "))

        while username < 4 or username > 12:
            print("That username is not within the boundaries")
            username = len(input("Please Enter a username between 4 and 12 characters: "))

        password = input("Now enter a password: ")
        password1 = input("Please re-enter the password: ")

        if password1 == password:
            print("Congratualtions on your new account")


        while password1 != password:

            print("They don't match")
            password = input("Now enter a password: ")
            password1 = input("Please re-enter the password: ")

            if password1 == password:
                    print("Congratualations on your new account")


        usernameinput = input("Please Enter your username: ")

        if usernameinput == username:

                print("Great job")

        while usernameinput != username:

                print("That is the incorrect Username")
                usernameinput = input("Please Enter your username: ")

                if usernameinput == username:
                        print("Great job")


Scenario2()
```

Whenever I enter the usernameinput the same as username. it doesn't say good job but that it is incorrect.

Could I get some help with this?

Comment: Can you reduce this down to a [mcve]? 99% of the code posted looks irrelevant.

Comment: How can this work? In one instance you call `len()` on input (so `username` is an int) and then you take a string for `usernameinput`.

Comment: username is a number (from len) and usernameinput is a string, so they will not be equal, so will not produce 'good job'

Comment: ok thank you very much, ill try to fix it

Answer (score 2):

```
    while usernameinput != username:

        print("That is the incorrect Username")
        usernameinput = input("Please Enter your username: ")

        if usernameinput == username:
                print("Great job")
```

This won't work because, you have assigned `username = len(input("Please Enter a username between 4 and 12 characters: "))` before this `while` loop, rename your variables for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

`Username` is being assigned as the length of the input, not the input. You need to introduce a separate variable to assign the input too.